# Use of selectedIndex on value changes to blank select

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript to change the value of a select when the input button is clicked.  When the button is clicked it changes the select to a blank value.

I've tried both `.selectedIndex = '20'` and `.selectedIndex = 20` and still get the blank result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDefault(){
    document.getElementById('Skill_1').selectedIndex = '20';    
}
</script>

<select id="Skill_1" name="Skill_1">
<option "selected" value="0" >Zero</option>   
<option value="20" >Twenty</option> 
<option value="40" >Forty</option> 
</select>

<input type='button' onclick='changeDefault()' value='Set Defaults'/>
```

Comment: How about `.value = '20'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedIndex` is the *index of the first selected `<option>`*. This is not the same as `value`, that option's value. It looks like you want the `<option>` at index `1` so

```
document.getElementById('Skill_1').selectedIndex = 1;
```

Alternatively you can set it using `value`, which will find the first `<option>` with a matching *value*.

```
document.getElementById('Skill_1').value = "20";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xPmw5/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use single quotes on the button?

And selectedIndex is an integer.

20 will always fail since your select only has 2 options.

Value 20 is index 0
Value 40 is index 1

You should use selectedIndex=0